# Following problem on topology $(\textrm{N.B.H.M} - 2015)$

Tags: general-topology, matrices

> let $X = \{ f \in C[-5 , 5] : f(-5) = f(5) = 0 \}$ . Then Which of the following statement are true :

(a) There exist $f \in X$ such that $f \equiv 2$ on $[-1 ,0 ]$ and $f \equiv 3$ on $[1,2] \cup [3,4]$

(b) For every $f \in X$, there exist distinct points $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $] -5, 5[$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$

(c) For every $f \in X$ , there exist $x \in ]-5, 5[$ such that $f(x) = x$

For (a) and (b), WE can solve by making a graph

For (c) define $ g(x) = f(x) -x$, So by intermediate value theorem there exist $x$ such that $g(x) = 0$ $\Rightarrow f(x) = x$

> Let $A \in \mathbb M_n(\mathbb C)$ and $\rho (A) = \textrm{max} \{|\lambda| :\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A $\}$ denote the spectral radius. Which of the following subset are compact?

(a) $S =\{ A \in \mathbb M_n(\mathbb C) : \rho(A) \leq 1 \}$

(b) $S =\{ A \in \mathbb M_n(\mathbb C) : A =A^* ~~\textrm{and} \ \ \rho(A) \leq 1 \}$

(c) $S =\{ A \in \mathbb M_n(\mathbb C) :  AA^* = A^*A = I \}$

For (a) No. Using the standard topology on $M(n,\Bbb R) \cong \Bbb R^{n^2}$, consider unbounded subset of upper-triangular matrices 
$$A_k = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & k \\ & \lambda_2 & k \\ & & \ddots & k \\ & & & \lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$$
with $k\to\infty$, $|\lambda_i|\le 1$ as we require, and all other entries $0$.

For (b) Since $A$ is hermitian matrix . So $A$ is diagonalisable. So $A$ can be written as

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 &  \\ & \lambda_2 & \\ & & \ddots  \\ & & & \lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$$

So $S$ is compact.

(c) Similarly we can show that $S$ is compact.

I would like somebody to check if I have done correctly and I would be thankful if any body can let me know if there is anything more to be specified.

Comment: Yes you are correct